# What is the analogy of interpreting a certain json date string and then using another date

Tags: javascript, json, date

I have this json date string here:

```
"/Date(1466977594519+0200)\/"  //comment: 18th August 1981
```

I need to test something and for this test I need a very new date like 2013-05-20.

When I create a date object with the above date (18th August 1981) and convert it to json:

```
var d = new Date(1981,07,18);
var str = JSON.stringify(d.getDate());
console.log(str);
```

Why has the json string this format:

`"18"` ?

I rather expected the very long number from above.

What is this 18 ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(new Date(1981,07,18).getDate());` returns `18` for me.

Comment: Maybe you have an error. `getDate()` returns the date portion of the date, which should be `18` in this case.

Comment: Looking up what the method `Date.getDate` does on your own was too much for you?

Comment: I corrected its now 18 was a typo.

Comment: So now it should be obvious where it comes from.

Comment: @Bitch new Date(1981,07,18).getDate(); returns 18 Why has a date only the day? Thats not logical.

Comment: Because getDay() returns the day of the week (e.g. Wednesday) and so they needed to use something else. Any method called getDate is going to be ambiguous when it belongs to a Date object

Comment: @RobJohnstone Thanks Rob for the explanation.

Comment: I agree the method name is confusing but the whole JS handling of dates is pretty horrible IMO. Wonder how many bugs have been caused by the decision to use zero based months.

Comment: @Martin Thats another thing... I also asked my self about zero based days... everything is twised lol

Comment: I agree, however 0-based months is more logical from a language perspective (everything else is 0-based) and also makes it handier to map the values to an array e.g. if you are storing the names of the months they will normally be 0-based: [Jan, Feb, ...], Jan is the 0th element in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDate` returns the day of the month not the date. You need:

```
var d = new Date(1981,07,18);
var str = JSON.stringify(d.getTime());
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I have now the date I want.